# Query on C# ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)

Tags: c#, servicestack

The property I am facing issue with is of FieldDictionary datatype that is not returning the value when sending a GET request and receiving the response in ServiceStack version 6.9
After upgrading from ServiceStack 4.5.14 to 6.9 Fields Value is Null in response.Results(Null Reference Exception in Fields Property)

*The structure of FieldDictionary property is as below:*

```
   [DataContract]
   public class ExampleClass
   {
    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(ExcludeInSchema = true, DataType = "object", 
    Verb = "NONE")]
    public FieldDictionary Fields { get; set; }
   }


   [CollectionDataContract(Name = "Field", ItemName = 
    "Field")]
    public partial class FieldDictionary : 
     Dictionary<string, IProperty>
    {
    }
```

so how do I create a web app wherein i send a get request and in the reponse i need to check FieldDictionary parameter's response values

Hence I am creating a reproducible web app of this issue to narrow down the root cause
below is what i have tried

**Program.cs**

```
using ServiceStack;
using Servicestackreplication;

namespace Servicestackreplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            AppHost appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();

            CreateHostBuilder(args, appHost as AppHostBase).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, AppHostBase appHost) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        // Register ServiceStack services
                        services.AddSingleton(appHost);
                    });
                });
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using ServiceStack;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Servicestackreplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }

        public void ConfigureContainer(Container container)
        {
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers(); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**AppHost.cs**

```
using Funq;
using ServiceStack;


namespace Servicestackreplication
{
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("ss", typeof(SampleService).Assembly)
        {
        }


        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {

            Plugins.Add(new SharpPagesFeature());
        }

    }
}
```

**MyServices.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

using ServiceStack;

namespace Servicestackreplication
{
    [Route("/sample", "GET")]
    public class SampleRequest : IReturn<SampleResponse>
    {
    }

    public class SampleResponse
    {
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public FieldDictionary FieldDictionary { get; set; }
    }

    public class FieldDictionary : Dictionary<string, IProperty>
    {
    }

    public interface IProperty
    {

    }
    public class SampleService : Service
    {
        public object Get(SampleRequest request)
        {

            var response = new SampleResponse
            {
                Name = "ah",
                Age = 30,
                FieldDictionary = new FieldDictionary
         {
    { "Key1", new PropertyImplementation() },
    { "Key2", new PropertyImplementation() }
          }

            };
            //Log.Debug($"Name: {response.Name}, Age: {response.Age}");

            //foreach (var entry in response.FieldDictionary)
            //{
            //    Log.Debug($"{entry.Key}: {entry.Value}");
            //}
            return response;
        }
    }

    public class PropertyImplementation : IProperty
    {

    }
}
```

**I am getting below error** in line in AppHost.cs

```
public AppHost() : base("ss", typeof(SampleService).Assembly)
        {
        }
```

**System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.IHttpHandler' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'**

Please help me resolve this

Comment: What does this have to do with Roslyn source generators? What does `not returning the value` mean? You get an exception? No field in the JSON response? An empty attribute> Does the `Fields` property have any value to begin with? At least post the code that returns this class as a result

Comment: What kind of project is this? Web API? MVC? ASP.NET Classic or Core? Is it based on a ServiceStack template?

Comment: Yes Fileds will have value. But in the response it will be null.

Comment: Post the code in the question, not the comments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited the post. Please take a look.